# C# web Api Long url Not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following web API url which is not working

```
www.localproject.com:843/api/user/validate/eyJhbGciOiJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAxLzA0L3htbGRzaWctbW9yZSNobWFjLXNoYTI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9eyJ0ZW1wVXJsIjoie1wiQ3VzdG9tZXJJZFwiOjEsXCJDb3Vyc2VJZFwiOjEsXCJUb2tlblwiOm51bGwsXCJFeHBpcnlcIjpcIjIwMTgtMDQtMThUMTc6MzU6MTMuOTQ2MjM2NCswNTowMFwifSJ9uvm7jZ3us5UFa1hqh4bod2cSamcxF2rRUbfxs7DHQs
```

whenever I hit the above url It gives me following error

```
Bad Request - Invalid URL

HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.
```

I updated my web.config to this as well but still not working.

```
 <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" maxRequestLength="20480" maxUrlLength="6144" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
```

I also tried editing registry but no luck.

How to allow long url using web api?

Comment: Did you add a hostheader for localproject and configure kestrel or IIS to listen on it?

Comment: what do you mean by adding header? where to add a header? I am hosting website on IIS

Comment: www.localproject.com will not resolve to an IP unless you have a host header or a dns entry for it.  Google "Windows Host Header".

Basically, you edit your hosts file and add localproject.com to 127.0.0.1.  Which lives by default at c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

Comment: could u share the controller class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, HTTP.sys permits 255 segments at a maximum length of 260 characters each. That 260 character limit is why you are seeing this issue.

To fix this you need to make a registry change.
Navigate to:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters

Add a DWORD value named **UrlSegmentMaxLength** and set its value to something like 500 or say 1000.

While you can probably avoid reboot by restarting the HTTP System Service thru command line is a possibility "net stop http" and "net start http", but because several other services depend upon this service like WWW, Print Spooler, SSDP Discovery etc. I will still recommend rebooting the server.